# Connecting to Elasticsearch via python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am running elasticsearch-8.6.1 with default settings on an Azure VM, with port 5601 open.  This is a dev server with only one cluster.  I am able to start Elasticsearch, Kibana and Logstash services and view them via a browser.

I have a some python code which is trying to connect to ElasticSearch using the recommended route of verifying https through the ca_certification route as per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/master/connecting.html

I have copied the http_ca.crt file from the VM onto my local machine and made it accessible.

```
   es = Elasticsearch('https://localhost:9200',
                   ca_certs=CA_CERT,
                   basic_auth=(USER_ID,ELASTIC_PASSWORD))
```

Elasticsearch.yml has the following enabled

network.host: 0.0.0.0

http.host: 0.0.0.0

xpack.security.enabled: true

I appreciate that I can turn off security, but this isn't a sustainable approach moving forward.

The error I am getting is

> elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by:
> ConnectionError(Connection error caused by:
> NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x000001890CEF3730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it))

I suspect there is some configuration setting that I am missing somewhere.

Thanks in advance for any advise or pointers that can be offered.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the Python code is unable to establish a connection to Elasticsearch on the specified host and port. There could be several reasons for this, including network configuration issues or problems with SSL/TLS certificates.

Here are some things you could try to troubleshoot the issue:

Check that Elasticsearch is running and listening on the correct host and port. You can use the curl command to test the connection:

```
curl -k https://localhost:9200
```

If Elasticsearch is running, you should see a JSON response with information about the cluster.

Check that the SSL/TLS certificate is valid and trusted by the Python client. You can use the openssl command to check the certificate:

```
openssl x509 -in http_ca.crt -text -noout
```

This will display detailed information about the certificate. Make sure that the Issuer and Subject fields match and that the Validity dates are correct.

Check that the firewall on the Azure VM is not blocking incoming traffic on port 9200. You can use the ufw command to check the firewall rules:

```
sudo ufw status
```

If port 9200 is not listed as "ALLOW", you can add a new rule:

```
sudo ufw allow 9200/tcp
```

Check that the Python client is using the correct ca_certs file. Make sure that the

> CA_CERT

variable in your code points to the correct file location.

Check the Elasticsearch logs for any error messages that might indicate the cause of the connection problem. The logs are usually located in the logs directory of the Elasticsearch installation.

Hopefully, one of these steps will help you resolve the issue. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this Elliot. I've tried each of the steps without success.